# 画像のリンクをhoverした際に下線が出るのを防ぎたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css

現在rails勉強中で、ブログアプリを作成しています。画像アイコンをルートに戻れるリンクにしているのですが、その画像アイコンをホバーすると下線が表示されます。

**これを出ないようにするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？**
調べた方法を試したのですが、うまくいきません。
cssを以下のようにするといった内容はよく見ましたが、うまくいきません。

> text-decoration: none;
> border: none;

現在の画面とcssの実装です。（cssは試している最中です）
▼application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HerokuApp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to image_tag('icon.jpg', class: 'logo'), root_path %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

▼application.html.erb

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
 .container {
     width: 400px;
     margin: 20px auto;
 }

 body {
     font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
 }

 h2 {
     font-size: 16px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 }

 ul>li {
     margin-bottom: 5px;
 }

 .logo {
     width: 10%;
     height: 10%;
 }

 a:hover {
     text-decoration: none;
     border: none;
 }

 a {
     text-decoration: none;
     border: none;
 }
```

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: a:hover の背景色がはみ出しているだけではありませんか？

Comment: おーそのようでした！ご回答いただきありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

menewさんにご返答いただき解消できました。

どうやら下線のように思えていたものは、背景色がはみ出しているようでした。
以下のように修正すれば解決できました。

> a:hover {
> 　　background-color: transparent;
> }

▼application.html.erb

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
 .container {
     width: 400px;
     margin: 20px auto;
 }

 body {
     font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
 }

 h2 {
     font-size: 16px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 }

 ul>li {
     margin-bottom: 5px;
 }

 .logo {
     width: 10%;
     height: 10%;
 }

 a:hover {
     background-color: transparent;
 }
```